# How to view TeXnicCenter PDF output with Adobe Acrobat and Adobe Reader?

Tags: viewers, texniccenter, adobe

I want to view the PDF output from TeXnicCenter with the latest version of Adobe Acrobat or Adobe Reader. How do I configure TeXnicCenter accordingly?

Comment: You shouldn't use any of them to view you pdf (at least as long as your document is not finished): they lock the .pdf file, and you have to close  it before being able to recompile.

Comment: @Bernard: I think you are wrong. A properly configured TeXnicCenter closes automatically before recompile.

Comment: Yes you to close , re-open, re-close,and so on. It's so much simpler to use a viewer which doesn't lock the .pdf!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be configured in TeXnicCenter under *Build* > *Define Output Profiles...*

**Reader DC 2017**: See image below

**Reader DC 2015**: Change *server* to `acroviewR15`

**Reader 11**: Change *server* to `acroviewR11` and *executable path* to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe`

**Acrobat DC 2017**: Change *server* to `acroviewA17` and *executable path* to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 2017\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe`

**Acrobat DC 2015**: Change *server* to `acroviewA15` and *executable path* to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 2015\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe`

**Acrobat 11**: Change *server* to `acroviewA11` and *executable path* to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 11.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe`

[image]