# TeXnicCenter does not open files in Adobe Acrobat Pro

Tags: miktex, windows, texniccenter, acrobat

I get the following error which is well known:
[image]

But I can't make it work and I don't want to change the Reader (I know, some people moved to Sumatra). Is there any chance to make it work in a non-random way?

Thank you very much for your support!

**Useful links** - I think I tried all possible combination :-(

- Concerning Sumatra [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161835/sync-between-adobe-and-texniccenter)
- Bug(?) "install on the fly" [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49338/miktex-2-9-install-packages-on-the-fly)
- Reader vs. Pro [link](https://mylatexnotes.wordpress.com/2017/07/31/texniccenter-adobe-reader-dc/)
- acroviewRxx-setting [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250472/texniccenter-adobe-reader-dc)

**My settings**:

[image]

[image]

**Edit 1** (Ulrike Fischer's input): Still not working. I tried A17 and R17. Both without success. (I don't update the picture above)
[image]

[image]

**Edit 2** (Ulrike Fischer's input): Still not working.
[image]

**Edit 3** (Ulrike Fischer's input): Good Idea, winedt takes A17-version
[image]

But the pdf is not opend after creation and it cannot be opened:
[image]

After closing Winedt, it says that the file is broken...

**Edit 4** (Ulrike Fischer's input): **...Solution...**

I used Winedt "PDF Search" button (Shift + F8). This gave the following
[image]

I then changed the setting in **TeXnicCenter** accordingly and now it went through! **Final settings**:
[image]

Comment: Yet SumatraPDF is the recommended reader under Windows. It allows direct and inverse search because it can manage the synchronisation files.

Comment: `acroviewA10` is certainly wrong. Try `acroviewA17` or `acroviewR17` or perhaps even 18 at the end.

Comment: Check if the path to acrord32.exe is correct,

Comment: Wrong server name and wrong path are the two obvious possible error causes. But my adobe pro version is newer so I can't check which server name would work with your version. Did you try A16? Did you google for other possible names?

Comment: You could also install a test version of winedt and check if it can detect the reader. If yes one can extract the value from there.

Comment: Can winedt open and close the reader between compilations? If yes: Winedt seems to use an uppercase AcroviewA17 and the exe is named Acrobat.exe and not AcroRd32.exe . Did you try this?

Comment: This solved the problem!!! :-) If you like, you can post this as answer. Is there any way to write some cookbook? You really saved my day!

Comment: FYI: I tried to collects TeXnicCenter commands for different Reader/Acrobat versions in this answer (got marked as a duplicate): https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385086/1236

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: May I ask you for a favor? Could you reopen this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514361/how-can-i-tell-texstudio-not-always-to-update-miktex) please? The updating process keeps going again, seemingly random, and I added the Texstudio ourput. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time later, it did not work again. Using the procedure above, the final solution now is

[image]

(Just check out out Adobe => Help => About / Info about Adobe)
I will update the answer, when I face the problem again...

**24.6.2019**: Seems to be **acroviewA19**!

Comment: Strange, it only didn't work since today!?